# Can Azure app service access files from github repository?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two separate git repos that were created on Azure DevOps portal. One where I keep my source code for a .net core web api and other where I store some text files. So when I deploy my web api to an app service, I would like it to make responses with contents of files that are kept on the second repository. I wonder if this is even possible? Can an app service access files that are stored on Azure git repo? Are app service apps published somewhere else where they cannot access their own source code? I would appreciate any help or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get items via the REST API.

[You can find the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Sample Request:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items?scopePath=/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/_Home.cshtml&download=true&api-version=5.1
```

Sample Response.

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "value": [
    {
      "objectId": "61a86fdaa79e5c6f5fb6e4026508489feb6ed92c",
      "gitObjectType": "blob",
      "commitId": "23d0bc5b128a10056dc68afece360d8a0fabb014",
      "path": "/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/_Home.cshtml",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/_Home.cshtml?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Murray for a super quick answer, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you can write some code to download your txt file you saved in github,then read it and get the content.The way to access git file,the upper answer has mentioned.
I hope it will do some help to you,wish you a nice day.